# Shortest paths on uncountable infinite graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Lets consider the weighted directed graph $G=(V,E,w)$ where the vertices are $V=[0,1]\subset \mathbb R$ (alternatively $V=(0,1]$ or $(0,1)$), $E = V\times V$ and the weights are given by a function $w :(V \times V) \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Is it possible to find an algorithm (given possibley some restrictions on $w$)

1. ... for finding shortest path from some $s$ to some $t$?
2. ... for finding an approximate solution to a shortest path?
3. ... for finding a shortest path of less than $n$ nodes (for some given $n$)?

Has this kind of problem studied before?

E.g. if $w$ is differentiable we can tackle problem $3$ by finding minima of the function $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{m-1}) := w(s,x_1)+w(x_1,x_2)+\ldots+w(x_{m-1},t)$$ for all $m\leq n$ using analysis.

Comment: Note that shortest paths need not exist - e.g. let $w(x, y)=(x-y)^2$. And we can even make examples where there is no shortest path using only 3 nodes! (Set $w(0, x)=1$ for $x<1$, $w(0, 1)=100000$, and $w(x, 1)=(1-x)^2$ for $x\not=0$.)

Comment: Good point. Thats why I also asked whether this has been studied for restricted $w$. And you do not even need an infinite number of nodes to get graphs without shortest paths (e.g. as soon as you have negative cycles).